# ¿se pueden inicializar los valores recibidos por parámetros sin declarar atributos? la clase Dinero no tiene esos atributos!

Tags: java

como puedo inicializar gasto y description sin  declararlos como atributos?
Por requisitos me exigen NO DECLARARLOS, sin embargo me piden que el constructor tenga esta estructura.

public class Gasto extends Dinero {

```
public Gasto(double gasto, String description) {
    super();
    
}

public String toString() {
    return "gasto: " ;
}
```

}

Comment: Hola User, así como está planteada tu pregunta, no tiene sentido, creo que has leído mal el enunciado, además sin ver el resto del código, es difícil saber que necesitas, los parámetros del constructor, no necesariamente tienen que inicializar un atributo, pero... si en la clase **Gasto**, **gasto** y **descripcion** no son atributos, que sentido tiene la clase?.

Comment: Eso mismo digo yo.  Por desgracia el enunciado no lo he leído mal. Me temo que debe estar incompleto. Gracias por tu punto de vista

Comment: Podr+ias subir el enunciado completo y la clase dinero?